# Does Extend Spell affect the duration of effects caused by spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, metamagic

I was wandering how Extend Spell affects certain spells. I know it doubles the duration, but does it double effects as well? Unless I'm missing something there doesn't seem to be a ruling. It says it doesn't work with "instantaneous" spells, but never says anything on the effects.

For instance, it won't make the effect of color spray last twice as long, but what about, say, stinking cloud? It would make the duration twice as long, but what about the effect's duration? Would I get 2d4 rounds of being nauseated?

I'm sure a lot of people will answer with "well if it doesn't work with color spray, common sense says it wouldn't work with other effects either", but I'm looking for an actual written ruling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Extend Spell (Metamagic) doesn't do anything anything that it doesn't say it does.

[Extend Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/extend-spell-metamagic-final/) states:

> An extended **spell lasts twice as long** as normal. A spell with a duration of concentration, instantaneous, or permanent is not affected by this feat.

(Emphasis added)

It doesn't say anything about effects, just that the *spell* lasts longer. Therefore, side effects and conditions caused by the spell last the normal duration.

### Empower Spell (metamagic) does what you want.

[Empower Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/empower-spell-metamagic-final/) reads:

> All **variable, numeric effects** of an empowered spell are increased by half including bonuses to those dice rolls.
>   Saving throws and opposed rolls are not affected, nor are spells without random variables.

Comment: Maximize as well